# Getting NullPointerException when running hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>      
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306/Test</property>
<property name="connection.username">user</property>
<property name="connection.password">12345</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<mapping class="net.codejava.hibernate.Book" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my class:

```
BookManager.java

package net.codejava.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class BookManager {
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 protected void setup() {
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
            .build();
    try {
        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }
}

protected void exit() {
    // code to close Hibernate Session factory
}

protected void create() {
     Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle("Effective Java");
        book.setAuthor("Joshua Bloch");
        book.setPrice(32.59f);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(book);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BookManager manager = new BookManager();
    manager.setup();
    manager.exit();
}
}
```

And i got this NPE error:

```
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:25 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.6.Final}
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:25 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:25 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306/Test]
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=elop, password=****}
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
kwi 02, 2017 8:06:26 PM org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl stopService
INFO: HHH000369: Error stopping service [class org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and don't have idea what is wrong with this project..

Comment: is this all the stack trace you have?

Comment: Yes, that's all. I just spotted and error. I think <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> caused an error since i am using SQL Server..

Comment: yes. If you are connecting to sql s will cause an exception

Comment: shouldn't that configuration file be hibernate.hbm.xml ?

Comment: I don't know. It works with hibernate.cfg.xml.